Cormac McCarthy and syntax

He walks through the narrow streets of the port. The air smells of salt and newsawn lumber. At night whores call to him from the dark like souls in want. A week and he is on the move again, a few dollars in his purse that he’s earned, walking the sand roads of the southern night alone, his hands balled in the cotton pockets of his cheap coat. Earthen causeways across the marshland. Egrets in their rookeries white as candles among the moss. The wind has a raw edge to it and leaves lope by the roadside and skelter on in the night fields.

It's from 'Blood Meridian'.
Let's look at the last sentence:

The wind has a raw edge to it and leaves lope by the roadside and skelter on in the night fields.

What does 'a raw edge' mean? What's refered to by the pronoun 'it' in the 'The wind has a raw edge to it'?

Are you aware of [literature.se]?  This question is on topic, but if you want a more in-depth answer about Cormac's work, and the interpretation of it, then it can be a good place.  Here we limit ourselves to the basic meaning of the words and grammar, not to what the author suggests, invokes or alludes to.

It is a biting or cutting wind. It feels cold and unpleasant against the skin.
it refers to the wind.
Compare:
The song has a nice lilt to it.
The fabric has a soft feel to it.
"to it" expresses the notion "as one of its attributes".
That's really all there is to it.

I might add for clarity that blades (that cut) literally have [sharp] edges, as do, figuratively, harsh winds, cruel peoples' voices, their tone, etc.

Exactly. All is metaphor, but some metaphors have "broader spread" than others.
